# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11:

Tags: android, google-maps, inflate-exception

hi i want add google map to my project but i have errore and im not solve that

logcat:

```
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.LBS/net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  ... 11 more
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzJ(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzad(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzac(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzqs(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4716)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-07 06:19:26.849: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  ... 21 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package net.learn2develop.LBS;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions; 

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {   

    private GoogleMap mMap;         
    @Override     
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            setContentView(R.layout.main);             
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();         
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);         
            final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);         
            Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()                                   
            .position(CIU).title("My Office"));     
        }     
    @Override     
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.         
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);         
        return true;     
        }
    }
```

main.xml

```html
  <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
 android:layout_width="match_parent"    
 android:layout_height="match_parent"    
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <TextView        
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
 android:text="hello_world" />
 <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"     
         android:layout_width="match_parent"        
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.learn2develop.LBS"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
        <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDciL7-T3BphxGv2q-A77vNrcyJQ_sTrgI"/>
        <activity
            android:name="net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception log clearly says to add this line in manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

For setting up Google Play Services API read this also

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score -1):

The Exception clearly say that the Android manifest missing meta-tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And in **XML file line no-11** check the  fragment & google-play service jar file. Add proper dependencies.